# How to specify "monospaced system font" for a UILabel in Launchscreen.storyboard using Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fonts

In Xcode version 11.5, I programmatically created a UILabel in my iOS project with the font

```
UIFont.monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 17.0, weight: .regular)
```

I would like to create a label with exactly the same font in Launchscreen.storyboard.  But Xcode's Attributes Inspector for this label offers me only the fonts "System" and "System Italic", not "System Monospaced".  How can I make the font of my label in Launchscreen.storyboard match the font of the label in my app?  I would be willing to open Launchscreen.storyboard "As Source Code" and edit the label's <fontDescription> element by hand, if I knew what to do.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: if your have created a custom label, then why wouldn't you just assign its font programmatically during it's init?

Comment: @LewWinczynski - In general, yes, but not for `LaunchScreen.storyboard`.